# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS not working in SQLite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to drop a table in onUpgrade() method of SQLiteOpenHelper. I am getting a weird error of "No such table" in the query:
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS certification_categories`.

The code is:

```
private static final String DROP_CERTIFICATION_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS certification_categories";
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
     db.execSQL(DROP_CERTIFICATION_CATEGORIES_TABLE);      
}
```

and the stacktrace is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main.Auction (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS certification_categories
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                                            at com.db.DataBaseHelper.recreate(DataBaseHelper.java:135)
                                                                            at com.db.DataBaseHelper.onDowngrade(DataBaseHelper.java:125)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                            at com.dao.SyncProgressDao.getUnfinishedAuctionIds(SyncProgressDao.java:45)
                                                                            at com.service.SyncProgressService.getUnfinishedAuctionIds(SyncProgressService.java:69)
                                                                            at com.background.AuctionSync.syncUnfinished(AuctionSync.java:102)
                                                                            at com.background.AuctionSync.onHandleIntent(AuctionSync.java:97)
                                                                            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: The code you posted is not where the error is happening. `at com.db.DataBaseHelper.recreate(DataBaseHelper.java:135)`

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints bound to the table?

Comment: onDowngrade ???

Comment: Show the entire database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this. Another table had a foreign key association with certification_categories table.

So, first dropping that table and then dropping certification_categories solved the issue.

However, they could've flagged appropriate error instead of 'no such table' to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

## open Database before dropping table...

```
private static final String DROP_CERTIFICATION_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS certification_categories";
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
         db = openorCreateDatabase("DB_NAME",this.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         db.execSQL(DROP_CERTIFICATION_CATEGORIES_TABLE);      
}
```